# Servlet Excel Download not working in IE8

Tags: java, servlets

I am using code from this site 
http://www.java-forums.org/blogs/servlet/668-how-write-servlet-sends-file-user-download.html

for downloading excel file from server. It working fine with Firefox,chrome but it is not working in IE8. Can any one help me to fix?

Note: It is not showing any error in IE8.

Comment: What is meant by not working ?

Comment: Did you turn on "Automatic prompting for file downloads" in IE 8 ?

Comment: @The New Idiot -- I Can't turn on "Automatic prompting for file downloads" for all End User IE browser

Comment: Hmmm , even your HTTP response can't force the download with custom security settings of browser !!!

Comment: @TheNewIdiot *"can't force"*  Amen to that!  It is my (damn) browser and if I want to download an XLS I'll configure the browser to do that.  OP:  I suggest you simple provide instructions to the IE users e.g. *"If you would like to **download** this file, go into settings.."*  In other words.  Empower the user, rather than trying to force them (or their browser) to do anything.